# rspec nested context strings concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, string-concatenation

in my rspec tests i have quite a few deep nested contexts like these:

```
describe "#mymethod"
  it_behaves_like "specific object"
end

shared_examples_for "specific object" do
  context "when it receives proper parameters" do
    context "when file is in a queue" do
      it "behaves as i want it to" do
       #...
    end
  end
end
```

as a result when i run my rspec tests i get results like those (or more complex) in sections "Pending"/"Failures"/"Failed examples":

```
mymethod behaves like specific object when it receives proper parameters when file is in a queue behaves as i want it to
```

those context strings sometimes tend to be unreadable for the lack of separators.

how can i monkey patch rspec to add them (f.ex. "|") automatically (or is there another preferred solution)? where do descriptor strings get concatenated in rspec?

Comment: Personally, I get around it by eliminating namespaces and only ending up in a final `context` namespace that can test `it { should be 'foo' }` blocks without any associated string. Testing on a pretty large and complex app and the tests are pretty readable.

Comment: are you running with `--format documentation`?

Comment: yes. actually i just noticed that my question applies only to "Failures" and "Pending" sections of rspec output. initial rspec's output ("Episode") looks properly(indented), which partially solves this problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec has the [notion of a separator hard-coded](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/350c21b6f66a54267ff615ed16604e017122e6be/lib/rspec/core/metadata.rb#L171-L183). Unfortunately, it is not configurable right now, but I guess the maintainers would consider a patch for review.

Comment: Btw I feel you as I'm yearning for this very feature: customizable separator. I've started looking at the code obviously, and when I have some time (?) will probably hack something.